# Map is off centered: I have to drag it to see my marker

Tags: performance, google-maps, center

This is my google map code, I literally just read watched tutorials to figure it out and have no idea about coding. Everything works but when I test it the map is not centered. I'm floating over the ocean and have to drag the tip of the island to see my bubble/marker. Thank you in advance for your patience and help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Creating a Custom Popup</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      /* The location pointed to by the popup tip. */

      .popup-tip-anchor {
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        /* The max width of the info window. */
        width: 200px;
      }
      /* The bubble is anchored above the tip. */

      .popup-bubble-anchor {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: /* TIP_HEIGHT= */
        8px;
        left: 0;
      }
      /* Draw the tip. */

      .popup-bubble-anchor::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        /* Center the tip horizontally. */
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        /* The tip is a https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ */
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        /* The tip is 8px high, and 12px wide. */
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-top: /* TIP_HEIGHT= */
        8px solid skyblue;
      }
      /* The popup bubble itself. */

      .popup-bubble-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
        /* Style the info window. */
        background-color: skyblue;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 60px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="content">
      Paddle Core Fitness!
    </div>
    <script>
      var map, popup, Popup;

      /** Initializes the map and the custom popup. */
      function initMap() {
        definePopupClass();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 21.9, lng: -157.8
          },
          zoom: 10,
        });

        popup = new Popup(
          new google.maps.LatLng(21.286891, -157.846388),
          document.getElementById('content'));
        popup.setMap(map);
      }

      /** Defines the Popup class. */
      function definePopupClass() {
        /**
         * A customized popup on the map.
         * * @param {!google.maps.LatLng}position
         * @param {!Element} content
         * @constructor
         * @extends {google.maps.OverlayView}
         */
        Popup = function(position, content) {
          this.position = position;

          content.classList.add('popup-bubble-content');

          var pixelOffset = document.createElement('div');
          pixelOffset.classList.add('popup-bubble-anchor');
          pixelOffset.appendChild(content);

          this.anchor = document.createElement('div');
          this.anchor.classList.add('popup-tip-anchor');
          this.anchor.appendChild(pixelOffset);

          // Optionally stop clicks, etc., from bubbling up to the map.
          this.stopEventPropagation();
        };
        // NOTE: google.maps.OverlayView is only defined once the Maps API has
        // loaded. That is why Popup is defined inside initMap().
        Popup.prototype = Object.create(google.maps.OverlayView.prototype);

        /** Called when the popup is added to the map. */
        Popup.prototype.onAdd = function() {
          this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(this.anchor);
        };

        /** Called when the popup is removed from the map. */
        Popup.prototype.onRemove = function() {
          if (this.anchor.parentElement) {
            this.anchor.parentElement.removeChild(this.anchor);
          }
        };

        /** Called when the popup needs to draw itself. */
        Popup.prototype.draw = function() {
          var divPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.position);
          // Hide the popup when it is far out of view.
          var display =
            Math.abs(divPosition.x) < 4000 && Math.abs(divPosition.y) < 4000 ?
            'block' :
            'none';

          if (display === 'block') {
            this.anchor.style.left = divPosition.x + 'px';
            this.anchor.style.top = divPosition.y + 'px';
          }
          if (this.anchor.style.display !== display) {
            this.anchor.style.display = display;
          }
        };

        /** Stops clicks/drags from bubbling up to the map. */
        Popup.prototype.stopEventPropagation = function() {
          var anchor = this.anchor;
          anchor.style.cursor = 'auto';

          ['click', 'dblclick', 'contextmenu', 'wheel', 'mousedown', 'touchstart',
            'pointerdown'
          ]
          .forEach(function(event) {
            anchor.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
              e.stopPropagation();
            });
          });
        };
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBp4smaJjQflG_wooY9rfd7EtaKcxv9TYY&callback=initMap">


    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a more precise map center by putting the same longitude and latitude as your pop-up.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 21.286891, lng: -157.846388 },
  zoom: 10,
  });
```

Comment: sorry for sounding ignorant- where would I place this? On what line?

Comment: Oh, it worked I figured out where to place what you recommended!!! Thank you soo much!